# Paypal - charge customer an unknown amount at a later date

Tags: php, paypal

We have a site where we need to charge the customer an upfront fee, and then when they complete a process at a later date, we will charge them another amount for which we only have an estimate.

What is the best way to do this with PHP SDK?

Do I need to use the Classic API?  Is a regular Billing Agreement (subscription) required?

Comment: have you get any solution for the same...

Answer (score 0):

Reference Transactions are not currently available in the Paypal PHP SDK, but they are working on it.  You can do it with the Classic API.